# How can I display a login and registration form, with an extra field on registration, and hybridauth in a modal?

Tags: 7, users, chaos-tool-suite, authentication-authorization

I need to display a modal login and registration form if a user accesses a particular page.

On the registration form, I need to collect a phone number.

I need to show the hybridauth login on the form as well.  Is there a solution, or compatible modules to make this solution?

It's a common login/registration solution, so I'd think Drupal has this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this has a common solution with preexisting modules. Here's the summary with your 3 requirements:

- **Forcing capture of telephone on registration:**

  - After enabling the [Telephone module](https://www.drupal.org/project/telephone), you can add a phone field on a user entity (http://example.com/admin/config/people/accounts/fields). When you create the field, make sure the **Display on user registration form** & **Required field** checkboxes are ticked to enforce user submission of this data on registration & edit.
- **Hybridauth Social Login:**

  - After enabling the module, and installing the libraries to the sites/all/libraries directory, configure each social network and set your other login options accordingly.
- **Modal Popup:**

  - The [Modal Forms module](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms) enables popup modals for the both the **user/login** & **user/register** paths. The popup presents the same login form as you see in Drupal so it will contain the HybridAuth login elements as well. The module lets you configure modal popups on a per-page basis so you can choose the pages where you want login/registration presented as modal form.

Comment: This looks like it will be the solution.  Any idea how I can prompt the login based on some custom logic?

Comment: You could probably trigger a jQuery click event for the rewritten user/login menu path, if you're wanting to do this on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

You could use webform & webform rules to create a user with more details than the standard registration page.

For HybridAuth-- would this be the module you're looking for? https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth

Comment: I already know the hybridauth module.  I need to be able to use it in a modal form.

Comment: Than this won't help you much, will it. Sorry